# How to overcome the lagging of typing in the editor while using ReSharper?

Tags: performance, visual-studio-2013, resharper

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 with ReSharper 9 on a quite strong computer (16GB RAM, Core i7 CPU, SSD, etc.). Still I experience heavy delays and laggings during typing for example in a C# or Razor source file.

I've noticed that every time I hit a key, the processing immediately starts, and context actions, offering rename refactorings, autocompetion immediatley shows up in the editor. It would make sense to delay these stuff for example so that all of this processing would start only when I finish typing and have some amount of quite milliseconds.

I've browsed through the settings for the third time now, but could not find anything related. Is there anything like this? If yes, where? If no, what else could I do to overcome this lagging? It's really annoying and I don't quite understand it. I can't beleive that such a computer is still not enough.

Comment: First make sure it *is* R#. Disable all other plugins and see if the symptoms  come from elsewhere or are from a bad interactions. While R# "isn't the fastest" it should not feel like typing on a [Macintosh](http://oldcomputers.net/macintosh.html) (and yes, it was painfully laggy in the word processor) with that hardware.

Comment: I've done this already, and without ReSharper everything gets fast and responsive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be seeing a lag while typing. I'd suggest disabling other extensions to see if there's a clash - something that ReSharper doesn't like being installed at the same time. Alternatively (or better yet, as well) you can profile Visual Studio to see what's going wrong. Go to ReSharper → Help → Profile Visual Studio, and ReSharper will download the profiler, attach to Visual Studio and start to gather info. Once you've demonstrated the problem, click "Get snapshot", and ReSharper will save the snapshot and add it to the dialog as an attachment. You can then describe what you were doing and submit the snapshot and description to the dev team.

I'd also suggest downloading the latest build - the [9.2 EAP](http://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2015/06/29/early-access-to-resharper-9-2-resharper-c-1-1-dottrace-6-2/) has just started, and contains a number of fixes that might help performance under certain circumstances.

Also, what are you typing in - what language, what size file?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was typing into a relatively small CS file, but also experience issues when typing into CSHTML files. I don't have any other extensions installed except for those installed by Visual Studio installer (I disabled or uninstalled most of them too). I'll try the profiling, I didn't know about this possibility. However, now I've cleared the ReSharper caches and things got better. Don't know how long it will last though. I will accept this answer because overall it was helpful and gave some useful ideas.

Answer (score 2):

Disable Bing Developer Assistant extension if you have it by going to 'Tools -> Extension And Updates'.
Disable the Microsoft Git Provider Plugin by going to 'Tools -> Source Control -> Then setting the Plug-In ComboBox to NONE.'

The above has helped me and has improved performance on my PC. Hopefully it will help you too.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see anything like Bind Developer Assistant (fortunately). I've also disabled the Git provider earlier. Useful ideas though.

Comment: Well, if you dont see the Bing Developer Assistant means that you haven't installed before. For me, it caused ReSharper Intellisense to slowdown.